# Snowflake - is it limit to see Query History only 7 days by default?

Tags: database, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I was trying to see queries for past month but based on this discussion - it looks like it goes back only 7 days...

https://snowflakecommunity.force.com/s/question/0D50Z00007sKN2vSAG/will-informationschemaqueryhistory-capture-the-details-of-current-running-query-

Is this true? Can we increase default?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can query `snowflake.account_usage.query_history` view for past queries.
This view has the history of all queries up to a year with 45 minutes lag.

https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/account-usage.html#account-usage-views

Information schema views have only limited data, usually up to 7 days unlike `account_usage` which has data up to a year.

[Comparison of information_schema and account_usage](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/account-usage.html#differences-between-account-usage-and-information-schem)

Update: How to get access to `SNOWFLAKE` db

By default, the SNOWFLAKE database is available only to the ACCOUNTADMIN role

You need to grant privileges to the role you are using in order to query SNOWFLAKE db. Since it's an imported db you need to use

`grant imported privileges on database snowflake to role ...`

Comment: Getting `Database 'SNOWFLAKE' does not exist or not authorized.`

Comment: You need to grant privileges to the role you are using in order to query `SNOWFLAKE` db. Since it's an imported db you need to use `grant imported privileges on database snowflake to role ...`